# How to have two text inputs communicate with each other (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native, and currently have two text input boxes and I would like it that when I change one the value shown in the other also changes. But then you will be allowed to edit the second text input and this will in tune change the first one. And so on...

I have tried setting the placeholder as the value, then that will change as the first text input changes, but it only works until you edit the text box.

Essentially I cannot figure out a way to have a text input and output on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
state = { valueOne: '', valueTwo: '' }

changeValueOne = (valueOne) => {
  this.setState({
    valueOne,
    valueTwo: `${valueOne}-foo`
  })
}

changeValueTwo = (valueTwo) => {
  this.setState({
    valueOne: `${valueTwo}-bar`,
    valueTwo
  })
}

render() {
  const { valueOne, valueTwo } = this.state
  return (
    <View>
      <Input onChangeText={this.changeValueOne} value={valueOne} />
      <Input onChangeText={this.changeValueTwo} value={valueTwo} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do except for one detail. Can you show how you would manipulate "valueTwo" before it is displayed. For example, I type 2 in the first bar and there would be a function that multiply's the first number by 3 and display's it on the second bar. So I type 2 in the top and 6 gets displayed on the bottom. I have gotten real close to doing it, but the displayed value is always one iteration behind the typed value when I try to manipulate it. THANK YOU

Comment: You can update the function for `onChangeText` to do something like this,


```changeValueOne = (valueOne) => {
  const valueTwo = parseInt(valueOne) * 3
  this.setState({
    valueOne,
    valueTwo: `${valueTwo}`
  })
}```

Comment: For my purpose I would like: const valueTwo = this.state.calculation. Where the value for "this.state.calculation" is being changed when the valueOne changes. My problem I keep having is that the output is one iteration behind when. So handleChangetext goes, I run my calculate function that results in a number for "this.state.calculation" and I want that value to population valueTwo, but it will show the result of the previous iteration, not a live update. I very much appreciate the help, I am learning a lot. Thanks again

Comment: Right now I run handleChangetext and this first thing called is: this.calculate(variable,valueOne); that function sets the state of "calculation" and I would like that to be what shows up in valueTwo.